# Tutorial on DOM parser

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hi I had been looking for good tutorial on ***DOM parser*** more than an hour, but couldn't find not even one. so can anyone help me with good tutorial on DOM parser.

Comment: what kind of tutorial? eg Do you want to use a dom parser or write one? I assume you want to how to use it, but then in what context? The question doesn't provide enough information to give a useful answer.

Comment: @Spudley: i just wanna know the working of the Dom parser.Most of the sites i just find lines of code implementing the Dom parser without proper explanation.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks Robert ....I did go through Simple XML , and I found that it would be really helpful for me..

Comment: If you want to go with the DOM parser that is fine but may I recommend Simple XML instead? https://massaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) - it got all options of parsing including examples.

Comment: Thanks idroid ,but it has only code and no explanation is given. comparison with the SAX is given.

Comment: But it also says _It works exactly as it works in Java code that you would run on a desktop machine or a server_. So you can basically just google for **java dom parser**... [More source code examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/0040__DOM-Parser.htm)